# "like" pattern search in Drupal view

Tags: php, drupal, view, sql-like

I want to use **like** pattern search in Drupal View query.
Is it possible by using contextual filter?
To make it more clear, lets say search value is "test".

Default search query is where:

```
WHERE (( (field_data_field_design_code.field_design_code_value = 'test') )
AND(( (node.status = '1')
```

I want it like:

```
WHERE (( (field_data_field_design_code.field_design_code_value like '%"tes"%') )
AND(( (node.status = '1')
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Which version of Drupal are you using?

Comment: Hi, Sorry my mistake.
It's Drupal 7

Answer (score 3):

You can use View Query alter. In query alter you will get an object of the query.In this object you can inject what ever you want- 
[Views Query Alter Example](https://api.drupal.org/api/views/views.api.php/function/hook_views_query_alter/7)

Answer (score 1):

You can use db_query as below:

```
db_query('SELECT node.nid, node.title FROM {node}
INNER JOIN field_data_field_design_code ON node.nid = field_data_field_design_code.nid
WHERE field_data_field_design_code.field_design_code_value LIKE \'%%"%s"%\' AND node.status = %d', $keyword, 1);
```

You need to use %% in db_query to use LIKE, http://drupal.org/node/56400#comment-161218.